# Can't make accumulate to work properly

Tags: drools

I have the following class structure (Class A contains Class B):

```
class A {
    B object;
    ...
}
```

and I'm trying to do something whenever the average of the accumulation of a specific field in class B is above a given value.

so I'm trying to write the following :

```
when
   A($var1 : object)
   accumulate( B($num:num) from $var1;
               $avg1 : avg ($num); $avg1 < 10000)
then ...
```

what happens is that instead of accumulating all entities in the session and calculating the average for all of them, the average is being calculated on each entity separately.
so if the session already contains 5 numeric values which bigger than 10000 and another one is inserted then the "then" part is invoked 6 times (each one with average value the equals to the numeric value itself) instead of only once.

Do you have some hint that might help me to solve that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accumulate over all A facts accessing the field `num` of field `object`.

```
when
  accumulate( A( $var1: object );
              $avg1: avg($var1.getNum()); $avg1 < 10000)
then ...
```

Inserting all B objects as facts as well would permit you to write the straightforward

```
when
  accumulate( B( $num: num );
              $avg1: avg($num); $avg1 < 10000)
then ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. However one thing I forgot to mention is that class B is abstract and the numeric value is inside one of its children. Can I cast class B to the right children in this case?

Comment: Which case is "this case"? A B is a B, even if abstract, and a SuB extending B is a B, too,

Comment: If field num is in just one (not all) of the subclasses you can't do this in such a simple way, because the interface defined by B doesn't exist. But then your original code wouldn't have compiled.